# How to make all apps run as Administrator in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uac

How do I make every app / software run as administrator in windows 10, without breaking the calculator?

I'd prefer to simply remove UAC and have the apps run with the credentials I am logged in with, however this breaks the "universal" apps from running at all.
I would like a compromise: all apps running as administrator, but still allowing the universal apps to work.

Comment: Don't do this. Just. Don't. Do. It.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn we wouldn't be much of "superusers" if we can't setup the machines to do our bidding would we? I don't mind having UAC running, I mind when it prevents me from doing the things I need to.

Comment: Turning off UAC is like running as root in linux. It's just a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable **UAC** entirely from control panel which will effectively run with the privileges you currently have to grant manually

you can adjust the level of UAC to suit your needs. In decending order of strength, the settings are as follows :

Set as **Never notify** [If logged on as an admin-level user everything is automatically given elevated permissions.
If you are logged on as a standard-level user, anything that requires elevated permissions will automatically be denied (with no opportunity to enter a password in a UAC pop-up)].

Else you could disable The entire uac by modifying the registry :

1. Open registry editor
2. Navigate to the following location

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

3. At the right hand side modify the value of the EnableLUA DWORD value and set it to '0'

[image]

Note: If you do not have this DWORD value, then create it.**For security reasons please dont do this setting**

Restart your computer

Comment: no, moving the slider down no longer disabled UAC completely since Windows 8. UAC is required to run store apps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 updated answer

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 - Disabling UAC breaks modern apps, so it is not an solution. The OP already mentions this.

Comment: Peter already explained it. You disabled now the possibility to run any store app like calc and also other shell parts (Startmenu, action center).

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. With any of those suggestions my apps will not run in administrator by default, except for the registry option, which will prevent the use of windows store apps. I need to be able to run apps as administrator AND use the metro apps

Comment: THANK YOU for not succumbing to peer pressure and explaining this option for those of us who want to run every app as Administrator and not care about Store/Metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to run apps as administrator AND use the metro apps

This is impossible. The Store apps run sandboxed and this sandbox requires a turned on UAC.

[Use the Task scheduler workaround to start applications as admin without accepting an UAC prompt](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472).

Comment: You can run an app as an administrator with UAC on silent mode, that isn't impossible, I just need to script / configure this to happen on all my software where having it run as a simple user breaks the software. Maybe a script?