# Why do I have to run installers as administrator, when I'm the only account on this computer? (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, administrator

I am the only user and only account on my computer, but whenever I try to run an installer, I have to do run it as an Administrator or else it will fail (usually with an error message along the lines of "don't have permission"). Why is this?

I've checked the Security tab of my Downloads folder and various .exes, and all of the users show the same permissions:

[image: permissions]

("Special Permissions" is unchecked for all users)

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why do you have an unknown account listed?  That isn't normal

Comment: I believe you need to allow Admin access for the same reason you need sudo for certain operations in Linux. You're attempting to modify system-wide files/settings, and the admin prompt is an extra confirmation for this. The only way to disable this (that I know of) is by disabling UAC prompts.

Answer (score 1):

File permissions are distinct from the permissions with which a program runs. You correctly determined that your account has full access to that file, and therefore you can, among other things, run it. However, the powers of the new process that's created from that program are not fully determined by the file's access control list.

Windows has a feature called User Account Control that tries to help contain damage from malicious programs. Your user account is an administrator, but UAC makes it so most programs running as you do not have administrative powers - the "token" of the process (which determines its security-related abilities) has been watered down. When you run a program as administrator, UAC gives the new program the unfiltered token, allowing it to take advantage of all the privileges available to you as an administrator.

You can disable UAC, but doing so completely will break a lot of things on Windows 10, so it's not a good idea. If you want to do it anyway, [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/963935/380318) should work.

Technical reading: [How UAC Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835548(v=ws.10).aspx) at TechNet.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior.

Since Windows 7, security has been enforced drastically because in Windows XP it was just too easy to get infected with viruses.

UAC (User Account Control) was implemented which basically means, every action that modifies the system will require an approval of an administrator. If your account has administrative rights, you only have to click OK. If your account does not, a login screen will appear requiring you to enter credentials for an account with administrative rights.

That said, it is not possible for a program/virus/etc to press the OK button on the UAC dialog.

It is possible to disable UAC, but if you do that, then viruses can install freely on your system without your knowledge.

Keep in mind that when you run a program, this popup comes up and you press OK, and the program appears to be a virus, you will still get the infection.

Also good to know, nowadays malware and viruses will spread in a limited fashion as they try to nest in locations that do not require administrative access. This severely limits their abilities though, and as such, it usually does not come to a reinstall as it used to be with Windows XP.